# How to use JSoup to get hyperlink href?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have the following jsFiddle

> http://jsfiddle.net/B5zvV/

I am trying to use JSoup to obtain the value of the hyperlink's `href` string on Line 238:

```
<a href="/chain/admin/config/editRepository.action?planKey=AB-CSD&amp;repositoryId=28049450">
```

Hence, the desired result would be to obtain a String with a value of:

```
/chain/admin/config/editRepository.action?planKey=AB-CSD&amp;repositoryId=28049450
```

Here's my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://myapp.example.com/fizz.html").get()
Elements elems = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("href", "repositoryId")
```

When I run this, the value of `elems` is empty: **why, and what do I need to do to get the desired String?**

Comment: do you have the href with value containing repositoryId or just the href value?

Comment: Thanks @SyamS (+1) - I guess I don't understand your question. I am trying to parse the HTML file (`fizz.html`) in the jsFiddle link above. In that HTML file, on line 238, is a hyperlink (`<a>` tag). I want that specific hyperlink's `href`, no other ones. Ultimately, all I'm interested in is the `repositoryId` substring inside the href, but I can parse that out later, after the JSoup code.

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByAttributeValueContaining()` method will return multiple values in this case  because many `hrefs` has repositoryId. If you are particular about line 238 then that `a` is enclosed inside an `li` with class `item item-default`. There is only one such `li` and two a tags inside it. Just take the first one like

```
String html = "<li class=\"item item-default\" data-item-id=\"28049450\" id=\"item-28049450\">"
                + "<a href=\"/chain/admin/config/editRepository.action?planKey=AB-CSD&amp;repositoryId=28049450\">"
                    + "<h3 class=\"item-title\">MCAppRepo <span class=\"item-default-marker grey\">(default)</span></h3>"
                + "</a>"
                + "<a href=\"/chain/admin/config/confirmDeleteRepository.action?planKey=AB-CSD&amp;repositoryId=28049450\" class=\"delete\" title=\"Remove repository\">"
                    + "<span class=\"assistive\">Delete</span>"
                + "</a>"
            + "</li>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elems = doc.select("li.item.item-default > a");
System.out.println(elems.first().attr("href"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Syam S (+1) - however I get a NPE on the 3rd line, because `elems.first()` is returning NULL. Thoughts?

Comment: That is because the select didn't return anything. Are you referring to that html.